# How to disable Static Files feature in .Net Core API?

Tags: c#, .net-core

I'm migrating my WebAPI to .Net Core, the project contains razor files (.cshtml) which I'll compile at runtime when a method is called and return an HTML file.

Before migrating, all files were accessible to use, after that, I can only access the files under `"wwwroot"`, excluding file types like .cshtml which are always hidden when deployed on Azure.

It's working perfectly on my machine, the issue is when it's deployed live.
I've tried adding and removing `app.UseStaticFiles().`

I'm using Razorlight to access the razor templates, it's throwing an error saying that the file doesn't exist.

Comment: Are the `cshtml` files included when you deploy to azure? If you are using Azure WebApp you can navigate to <your-web-app-name>.scm.azurewebsites.net and browse the file system of your web app. Can you confirm that the files have been deployed?

Comment: I've checked the availability of the files via FTP, it seems that the .cshtml files aren't being uploaded, only css, js, and images files are showing under the wwwroot.

Answer (score 4):

`app.UseStaticFiles()` only serves the web root(wwwroot) directory. If you need to serve static files from outside the web root directory then you need to set up the `StaticFileOptions` as shown below.

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
{
    app.UseStaticFiles(); // For the wwwroot folder

    app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
    {
        FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(
            Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "MyStaticFiles")),
        RequestPath = "/StaticFiles"
    });
}
```

You can then serve files from `MyStaticFiles` directory like:

`http://<server_address>/StaticFiles/MyViews/test.png` serves the test.png file

See - [Static Files](http://%20https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files?view=aspnetcore-2.2)

As mentioned on the comments, ensure that `'MyStaticFiles'`(different in your case) exists by navigating to `<your-web-app-name>.scm.azurewebsites.net` and checking you project hierarchy.